# How to get dynamic path in a shell script?

Tags: bash, shell

I am writing a script that requires to get a dynamic folder path like this.

```
somefolder/prefix.datetime_suffix/foldera/folderb
```

datetime is  in format YYYYMMDDHHMMSS. **datetime part is changing.**

In a script I need to get a full path of *folderb* to move files there.

How can I do that?

Comment: what's your problem? to build the datetime string by a given datetime?

Comment: it is not known in advance :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have an inline `date` call in your path like:

```
    MYVARIABLE="somefolder/`date '+%Y%m%d%H%M%S'`/foldera/folderb/"
```

or (using the cleaner syntax)

```
    MYVARIABLE="somefolder/$(date '+%Y%m%d%H%M%S')/foldera/folderb/"
```

After setting the above variable, you could use it with `mv` command like:

```
    mv ./file.xyz $(MYVARIABLE)
```

Also, the man page for `date` lists all the formatting options.

Comment: Mark Howell's answer works perfectly well.  As a personal preference, I prefer this Bash syntax (assuming you are using Bash ...)

```somefolder/$(date '+%Y%m%d%H%M%S')/foldera/folderb```

Because my brain parses balanced parens more easily than equal back-tic pairs

Comment: thanks but I need it in a variable. Sorry for confusion. I had to mention it)

Comment: I also like the $() format, though often use backticks because of fewer keystrokes.

Answer (score 0):

```
find /complete_path_to/some_folder -name folderb
```

Comment: thanks but I need it in a variable. Sorry for confusion. I had to mention it)